# Auto-complete in SQL query panel in PHPMyAdmin not working on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have the **LEMP** stack installed on *OS X* and *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*. (The *same* versions of all).

On the *Mac* the autocomplete works OOB, but in *Ubuntu* it doesn't, I don't see any hints when I start typing. I've been googling for this but no success. I checked `demo.phpmyadmin.net` and it does work.

Is it a JS issue or in **PHPMyAdmin**'s config?

Comment: check your console for errors.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version is it? In which window are you attempting the autocomplete? Have you been using the same browser to access both servers, and if not can you try it to eliminate a browser issue as a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Please check is this is set.

```
$cfg['EnableAutocompleteForTablesAndColumns']
    Type:   boolean
    Default value:  true

    Whether to enable autocomplete for table and column names in any SQL query box.
```

the parameters are in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php (at least this is in my case)